# Chrome is caching service-worker.js even with Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache Max-Age: 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

Chrome v72 Seems to be ignoring Cache-Control headers and caching service-worker.js
To test, I've set all resources to use:

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private');
res.set('Max-Age', '0');
```

When navigating to localhost:4000/dist/service-worker.js I'm able to verify this is set correctly:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, private
Max-Age: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 23:17:55 GMT
ETag: W/"3c1-168ee4d6297"
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 961
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2019 23:27:24 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Even with this, as of Chrome 68, it "should" bypass the HTTP Cache by default:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw

It's clearly not.

I have *update on reload* checked in the Applications Tab. I have closed Chrome and reopened and it still is using the old service-worker.js from the cache.

My workbox config looks like:

```
        new GenerateSW({
            include: [/\.css$/, /\.js$/],
            clientsClaim: true,
            skipWaiting: true
        }),
```

I'm also able to verify, Chrome is caching the service-worker.js because if I:

- Open a new tab and navigate to:
  http://localhost:4000/dist/service-worker.js
- Chrome actually gets the LATEST, and now the other tab fires the "install" event.
- The other tab, now has the latest service worker.

The second to last test:

- Register service-worker.js
- Make changes, rename service-worker.js to sw.js (register sw.js)
- Navigate to http://localhost:4000 and see it's still using the cached service-worker.js
- Navigate to http://localhost:4000/dist/service-worker.js -> 404
  So even though it no longer exists, it's using the cached version.

The final test:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(`/dist/service-worker.js?hack=${Math.random()}`)
```

Of course, now it picks up all the new service-worker.js updates.

**Is this a Chrome Bug? Am I not configuring something correctly? This same behavior happens in Chrome Canary.**

Alternatively, I can do the following to bypass the cache:

```
            navigator.serviceWorker
            .register(`/dist/sw.js`)
            .then(registration => {
                registration.update();
            })
```

But this seems like a hack....

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a scoping issue due to the file being in /dist/service-worker.js and not in the root.

To fix the scoping issue I needed to add the following header to the service worker response:

```
res.set('Service-Worker-Allowed', '/');
```

Then when registering:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(`/dist/sw.js`, { scope: '/' });
```

Huge thanks to this article: 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/troubleshoot-and-debug

Comment: Where did you put that res.set part?