# Service worker ignores the fetch cache setting

Tags: javascript, service-worker

On a web page I have:

```js
let response = await fetch(url, { cache: "no-store"});
```

Then in the service worker I have:

```js
function handleFetch(event) {
    console.log(event.request.cache)  // Always prints 'reload', should be 'no-store'
}
self.addEventListener("fetch", handleFetch);
```

I require cache to be set to `no-store` not `reload`, i.e. the value it was set to. Chrome ignores the value and always changes it to `reload`. Am I doing something wrong or is this a case of Chrome inforcing its own value?

Further more to prove cache set correctly on the request I tried:

```
const init = { cache: "no-store"};
let request = new Request(url, init);
console.log(request.cache);  // Prints 'no-store'
let request = new Request(url, init);
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701679/9636400

Comment: @geertjanknapen Unfortnately not. My service worker is explicitly root scoped when registered, in a addition to being served from the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a Chrome bug:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1317680

I guess I will just use a custom header or Cache-Control header until its sorted out.

Answer (score 0):

From the MDN docs:

> *no-store* — The browser fetches the resource from the remote server without first looking in the cache, and will not update the cache with the downloaded resource.
> *reload* — The browser fetches the resource from the remote server without first looking in the cache, but then will update the cache with the downloaded resource.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache

So it seems that Chrome wishes to cache everything internally, because reasons, it might be some internal optimisation, and because of that supersedes your cache settings with their own, but respecting your wishes that you wish to have the "freshest data" by changing it to reload.

So you get the "newest uncached data", chrome gets to cache it for itself. Best of both worlds.

Comment: This is not the best of both worlds, I require it not to be stored in the cache afterwards, that part is very important for my application.

Comment: does it also use reload when dev tools are closed?

Comment: yes, if debug is closed, then I open it, it shows a large count of `reload`